# C-x g doesn't always open magit

Tags: magit

When I start `emacs` and press `C-x g`, it says: "C-x g is undefined". I can open a file belonging to the repository, and it still doesn't work. I need to start it manually (?) (`C-x magit-status`). And it's only after that that the keybinding starts working. But it still doesn't work in the `*GNU Emacs*` buffer, and in Dired. What's the supposed workflow? Should I add something to the config?

My current `~/.emacs`:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (magit))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Comment: Maybe if you post your current config someone might be able to help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Magit tries to establish that binding automatically using `global-magit-file-mode`. However that does not actually work. It's a known bug. You didn't mention this mode so I don't know whether you are aware that this mode is supposed to define that binding. But since it doesn't actually work that doesn't matter.

You have to define the binding yourself by adding something like this to your init file.

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c g") 'magit-status)
```

Comment: That's not particularly relevant, but recently I had to switch to `*terminal*` and back a lot. Which made me think of at least mapping `C-c b` to `C-x b`, and overall using `C-c` combinations in place of `C-x` ones. Is it possibly why you're mapping `C-c g`, not `C-x g`?

Comment: Because doing that in a package is forbidden. ;D

Comment: `C-c <letter>` is reserved for users and packages are not allowed to use it.

Comment: When a buffer is opened if magit is not on, can it enable itself automatically without the need of the keybinding? @tarsius